# How to pass tuple of args to multiprocessing pool imap?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

Is there any way to pass a tuple of arguments to multiprocessing `imap()`? I know this can be achieved with `starmap()` but the reason for wanting to use `imap` is because I want to wrap it around `tqdm` and because `starmap` does not enable you to see progress while imap does.

How can I see progress while passing a list of tuples as args in `multiprocessing`?

Consider the following:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
from multiprocessing import Pool

list_of_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)]

def func(a, b)
    return a+b


#This is what I want to do, but does not currently work
with Pool(self.pool) as p:
    fixture_info = list(tqdm(p.imap(func, list_of_tuples, chunksize=1), total=len(list_of_tuples)))
```

Comment: How about a wrapper function `wrapfunc(params): return func(*params)`?

Comment: @MichaelButscher Great suggestion, worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

list_of_tuples = [(1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 4)]


def func(a, b):
    return a + b


def temp_func(x):
    func(*x)

with Pool() as p:
    fixture_info = list(tqdm(p.imap(temp_func, list_of_tuples, chunksize=1), total=len(list_of_tuples)))
```